# Why calling method of another thread which changes volatile variable doesn't stop the thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I am writing a code using Java volatile keyword now and I am wondering why thread stops after I press enter for 2-3 times, not just 1 time.
The code:

```
public class RunThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        myThread.start();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.nextLine();

        myThread.shutDown();
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {

    public volatile boolean running = true;

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void shutDown() {
        this.running = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Your thread has a `Thread.sleep(1000);` so it does not stop immediately when you set `running` to `false`; it only checks the `running` flag once per second. So it can take up to a second before the thread stops.

Answer (score 2):

The `volatile` keyword is used when you need to keep a variable only in the main memory, instead of duplicating the variable in CPU cache. So, using a volatile variable is not relevant to the problem you're having.

I believe when you press enter, the value of `running` will become false. However, if the thread is asleep when you press enter, the program will not exit until the thread wakes up and starts the next iteration of the while loop. If you need to stop the thread immediately without waiting till it wakes up, you need to interrupt the thread. Use following code in your `shutDown` method in order to interrupt the thread.

```
public void shutDown() {
    this.running = false;
    this.interrupt();
}
```

Comment: I also thought about that but the problem is when I press enter once - nothing happens at all even I wait for several minutes. Even if I remove `Thread.sleep` invocation at all - still it doesn't work. Maybe there's something wrong with calling a method of an object which is basically another thread's object?

Comment: Maybe you should add a print statement after scanner.nextLine(), and make sure the program detects your keyboard interrupt. By doing that, you can ensure your keyboard input is received before the thread stops, and also your keyboard works properly ;)

Comment: There's no theoretical restriction on calling a method of an object of another thread.  So I think the issue is not related to the code if you have to wait for minutes after pressing enter.

Comment: Modern CPUs have coherent caches. Changes do not need to be pushed to main memory. This would be extremely inefficient. A thread running on some CPU that repeatedly accesses the same variable (could be volatile), could be fully served from its own cache without access to main memory.

Comment: @pveentjer I agree on your point. In modern CPUs usually L2 and/or L3 caches are coherent but usually L1 cache is dedicated per core. But chances of dirty read from L1 cache is extremely low due to cache size. So, use of volatile variables will be inefficient.

Comment: Also the L1 is coherent. There are no dirty reads.

Comment: If you would update a volatile variable in a tight loop, there would only be interaction with the L1 cache. Not as fast as a register, but still very fast access. And the cache line will continuously be in the MODIFIED state, so no need for any cache coherence traffic and certainly no need to push to main memory.

Answer (score 2):

From the code, I would say that you are just too impatient.

You start `main()`, that in turn triggers the new thread in `MyThread` (that does not run yet!), then `main()` starts an I/O operation that suspends it (the `scanner.nextLine()` line).

Now the other thread will be executed, prints "Hello" and goes to sleep for a second – and it will not return to life before this second has elapsed, no matter how often you hit ENTER!

When you hit ENTER the first time, `main()` proceeds, calls `shutdown()` (that will set `running` to `false`) and terminates. But because `MyThread` is not a demon thread, the JVM continues to run.

Now the second has elapsed, `MyThread` checks `running` (now `false`) and terminates, too.

So the program terminates after your first hitting ENTER, but your conception of that is different … all consecutive ENTERs are going to `/dev/null` or another type of limbo or void.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73305436/1554195) from Isuru Perera shows how you can modify your code so that the program (and the JVM) terminates after the first ENTER.

Comment: As I wrote to Isuru Perera, I also thought about that but the problem is when I press enter once - nothing happens at all even I wait for several minutes. Even if I remove Thread.sleep invocation at all - still it doesn't work. Maybe there's something wrong with calling a method of an object which is basically another thread's object?

Comment: No, that is not the issue. The instance of `MyThread` is created by the main thread and therefore, it "belongs" to it. Add some more `println` statements to see the sequence of execution. And what happens if you wait several minutes *before* you hit ENTER the first time?